# Vector layer of the Jerusalem city line ("הקו העירוני")

Tags: geospatial

I would like to guide a tour in Jerusalem sometime next week. For the historical and political perspective, I would be happy to show the [City Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Line_(Jerusalem)) on a modern Google Map during the tour. I can either use a existing vector data or georeference a high-quality raster city map.

I searched online, and only found rough sketches like the one below, taken from Wikipedia.

**Any idea where I can find an accurate map of the Jerusalem pre-1967 border?**

[image: Credit: Tamar Hayardeni, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Split_Jerusalem_map_English.jpg]

Comment: Have you contact any local university GIS department that they might have that hardcopy from them ? They may have it at their GIS lab.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [CShapes project](http://nils.weidmann.ws/projects/cshapes.html) has the data you want. It attempts to have all country boundaries from 1946–2008. Since this city line is also a country border, it should work for you.